# How did Cassie find out about the 4th wave?

Tags: 5th-wave

In *"5th Wave"*, Cassie was not present when the Army told the adults about the 4th wave right before murdering all of them.

Despite this, when she ran off into the woods she seemed to immediately know about it, based on her actions and narration. How did she find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassie stops trusting anyone when her father is massacred by the military.

After the bus with children leaves Cassie gets left behind. She returns to the barn where the adults are gathered, still carrying Bear. A gesture from her father makes that she remains outside.

At that point all the adults know the situation in the barn is not safe as the disguised aliens of the 4th wave 'could be right here in this very camp'.

Then the military shooting all the adults gives away the actual situation.

Reference: